# increment count by click on button mvc4 asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having an issue about how to express the increment by 1 , i really wish i could work this one out,

this is what is in my homeController

```
 public ActionResult OpenBidPanelOnItem( int _NumberOfVotes)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Place Vote on User Confirmation";
        Session["UserMessage"] = "Vote Success";     

        try
        {
            MyVoteModel _MyVoteModel = new MyVoteModel();            
            _NumberOfVotes =   _MyVoteModel.NumberOfVotes++;

        }
        catch
        {
            Session["UserMessage"] = "Vote Error";
        }

        return RedirectToAction("DisplayStore", "Home");
    }
```

and this is what i have in my view

```
using (Html.BeginForm("OpenBidPanelOnItem", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <button  type="submit"  value="Vote" style="background-color: green; width: 60px"> <b style="color:snow">Vote</b></button>

              @Html.Hidden("NumberOfVotes", Model.NumberOfVotes)

    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I cant increase the count of NumberOfVotes , its still 0 , i dont know how to display it :(

Comment: did u try to define int _NumberOfVotes as string?

Comment: No it is defined as int, why would it be string? , do you mean i should get it as string then i should generate it as numberOfVotes.count();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a postfix increment operator. The result of the operation is the value of the operand **before** it has been incremented. So if the value if the value of `NumberOfVotes` is zero (the default) when `MyVoteModel` is first initialized then `_NumberOfVotes` will be zero.

```
_NumberOfVotes =   _MyVoteModel.NumberOfVotes++; // return zero
```

Its not clear what the point of this is. You could use

```
_MyVoteModel.NumberOfVotes = ++_NumberOfVotes;
```

to increment the parameter value passed to the method and then assign that to a new instance of `MyVoteModel`, but then you redirect so the value would be lost anyway

Comment: It workes i can see its =1 , but how can i pass it corectly to the view?? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean when you redirect to the `DisplayStore` method?

Comment: no it is already redirectedto DisplayStore, but its not displaying in the view!

Comment: I mean, how to refresh the value of the numberOfVotes, coz its not in the database, its just a variable , how to pass it correctly?

Comment: Whats not displaying in what view? If you want to pass the incremented value to `DisplayStore` then `return RedirectToAction("DisplayStore", "Home", new { id = ++_NumberOfVotes );` but the code you have shown here makes no sense. Your method `OpenBidPanelOnItem` does not do anything except redirect. You create a new  instance of `MyVoteModel` but its immediately destroyed. Even your use of `@Html.Hidden("NumberOfVotes", Model.NumberOfVotes)` is pointless - it does not match the parameter name. I think you need to explain exactly what it is that your trying to do.

Comment: I need to increment the vote button count for each step by 1 ,  its in the displayStore view, it does increment but in the view it wont change from 0 to 1 , its like default 0

Comment: Sorry, but its still not clear, particularly as your code makes no sense, and you have not even included the code for the `DisplayStore` method (does it have a parameter `id`?). And since you never post back a value to the parameter `_NumberOfVotes`, its always 0 and the incremented value is always 1. And whats the point of the `try/catch` block (it can never throw and error!). I suggest you ask a new question clearly stating what it is you are trying to do, step by step, with the relevant controller methods and views.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain what you're asking here, but I'm going to take a punt. It might be the fact that the `Html.Hidden` is still using the same value that it was given the first time i.e. 0, and after POSTing, you find that 0 is still being passed to the viewmodel?

Incrementing that number does not result in the new value been displayed to the user. I mentioned this in a blog article:

http://mrclyfar.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/why-are-my-form-values-being-cached.html

To fix this, use this instead:

`<input type="hidden" id="NumberOfVotes" value="@(Model.NumberOfVotes)" />`